# How long should Unity 2D take to start up on old phones?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am in communication with a foreign programmer developing a 2D app using Unity 2017.3. The app is taking a long time to start up on old phones. For example on a Samsung Galaxy S3 you have to endure about seven seconds of a blank screen during the startup and on a GT-P3110 tablet its about 14 seconds! I have been hustling him to fix this problem for a few weeks but maybe it's not a bug at all. Maybe it's already as good as it gets? Can someone give me an indication of how long they would *expect* Unity to take to start up on these phones - and/or suggest a mechanism to avoid having to endure a blank screen during the startup sequence. It would be much better if it could say "Loading please wait" or some such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1: Loading Time**

It’s hard to tell without knowing your app, but 7 seconds on 6 year old phone sounds okay to me.

It all depends on how many assets (texture, audio clips,...) are referenced in the first scene, because Unity loads them all during startup and runs all scripts in the Awake() methods before drawing the first frame.

If the assets are actually not needed in the first scene, the developer could load them later on demand, but this requires additional work.

**Question 2: alternatives to a blank loading screen**

Instead of showing a blank screen, unity developer can define a static image as [splash screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidMobileCustomizeSplashScreen.html) that shows your brand name.

Additionally you can load as first scene an almost empty scene that just shows a text that says "Loading please wait", then after 1 frame it loads the previously first scene.